# Pair production through massless gauge mediator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, pair-production

I am wondering if it is possible for a massless boson to change the particle interacting with it, into another type of particle. In other words, is it possible to have a pair production process (in S channel) similar to the diagram below:

[image]

where $\gamma’$ is a massless guage boson similar to photon, and $\chi$ and $\psi$ are both fermions (or scalars) of different mass.
I know that it is allowed for a massive mediator (like W in the SM).

Do you have any arguments for or against this process?

Comment: @CosmasZachos This kind of $\bar{\chi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ vertex appears in a dark matter model after mass splitting.
I just want to make sure that this type of process is allowed where a particle is changed to another one through emitting a massless boson. I cannot see any problem with kinematics of the process.
What do you think?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My question is whether a massless boson can change the particle to another one with a different mass.

Comment: If the answer is useful, you can click on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your models and their caveats, so I cannot speculate how your effective field theory imagines this vertex, $ie'A'_\mu\bar \chi \gamma^\mu \psi $ + c.c., exists for massless vectors ***which are not gauge bosons***. The model should be non-renormalizable, but model-builders are pretty unscrupulous these days...

The Feynman diagram you have is meaningless Feynman-diagram-junk, as common in experimental talks with a Feynman-diagram fetish, in that it suborns the viewer  into assuming it represents a term in an existing legitimate theory, of the "you-know, you-know" type.

Let me  stress again what you must already know, namely that a massless gauge field $A'_\mu$ is *completely out of the question*, because it should couple to a conserved current, and your $\bar \chi \gamma^\mu \psi $ ***cannot be conserved*** unless *χ* and  *ψ* have the same mass, so the fermions have a global *U(1)* symmetry before the introduction of such gauge fields.

I have little experience with non-gauge vector fields, against which the whole world of Lorentz consistency is arrayed, but that is a very different question I would not touch.